# Android: Can we compress image using glide?

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-glide

Is it possible to use glide to compress an image picked from gallery or captured by camera before sending to server.

In other words is it okay to compress image like this:

1) Use glide to read uri and change to bitmap.

2) check size of bitmap.

3) adjust size of bitmap using Bitmap.creatScaledBitmap(....).

4) lower quality of bitmap.

5) then send.

Is it possible?

What benefits I get, if I already do it the old way:

1) get bitmap from file.

2) same stuff as above .....

Thanks.